# Elementary Number Theory: Legendre Symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Compute $(\frac{307}{379})$.

So what I did is as follows:

$(\frac{3}{379})= (-1)^{189\times153} (\frac{379}{307})= -1(\frac{72}{307})$.

Since $72$ is composite I spilt the legendre symbol into it's prime factors and got

$ -1(\frac{72}{307})=-1 (\frac{2}{307})(\frac{2}{307})(\frac{3}{307})= -1 \times -1 \times -1\times -1= 1 $ . So my $307$ is a quadratic non residue. I want to know if my work is correct because my friend and I got different answers. The way I obtained my answers $(\frac{2}{307})$ and $(\frac{3}{307})$was by using auxiliary laws.

Comment: Looks good.  An easy way to check is to numerically compute a square root.  $379$ is fairly small so this isn't too bad.  Indeed $38^2\equiv 307 \pmod {379}$.

Comment: I don't quite see what you have done to $72=2^3\times 3^2$. Since $72=6^2\times 2$ you can simplify somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-$$307\equiv (38)^2\pmod{379}$$ Can you  to know now if you are wrong or not?

Comment: yes, I can I did it wrong.

Comment: Exactly. But it's making mistakes that one learns almost always mathematics. A very useful exercise for you is to try to see where you were wrong. Regards.